# How to create an inline image as files in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, content

I'm having a rich text area in my lightning component. On clicking "Save" button, I want to create files if any inline image is added to that rich text area.

I'm having an idea that if I,m able to get the "Content-ID" value then I can take that image out and create it as an attachment. Is this idea correct? If not, please give me some suggestions.

Code Snippet:

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.Description__c}" placeholder = "Please enter here" >
 <lightning:insertImageButton/>
</lightning:inputRichText>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I can't see an option to add inline images in richTextArea in lighting aura , can you add your code snippet and screenshot?

Comment: I'm having a rich text area field in a custom object. And I have created a rich text area in my lightning component using lightning:inputRichText. On clicking "Save" I'm storing this value into that custom field. Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

The above requirement can be done via using "shareWithEntityId" attribute inside lightning:inputRichText. Here is the update code:

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.Description__c}" placeholder = "Please enter here" shareWithEntityId = "{!v.recordId}">
  <lightning:insertImageButton/>
</lightning:inputRichText>
</aura:component>
```